# Nginx rewrite question

Tags: nginx, rewrite

My goal is that requests for `/foobar?key=123` should redirect to `/download/foobar.html?key=123`.

I currently use the following code to accomplish this:

```
location /foobar {
  rewrite ^/foobar(.*)$ /download/foobar.html$1 permanent;
}
```

This does the trick, but we have some old code that also calls `/FooBar?key=123` and `/Foobar?key=123` which ignores the rewrite rule.

How can I get these to rewrite too?  Could use:

```
location ~* ^/foobar {
  rewrite ^ /download/foobar.html$1 permanent;
}
```

but isn't this a bit loose of a rule?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First off, `location` is case sensitive by default; `location ~* ^/foobar$` will fix this.

For the `rewrite`, it's always case sensitive, but you can make your expression match both forms:

```
rewrite ^/[Ff]oo[Bb]ar(.*)$ /download/foobar.html$1 permanent;
```

Comment: I think without the ^/foobar it could erroneously match somewhere else, like /images/foobar12.png.  Or does the rewrite ^/[Ff]... take care of that?

Comment: @jimg Indeed it will.  And without a trailing `$`, it'll also catch `/foobars`, so we'll add that, too (`location` doesn't look at the query params, so this will work just fine in your case).  Yes, the string limiting in the `rewrite` takes care of that - but if all you're doing in that location block is the rewrite, then you can probably just get rid of the `location` completely.

Comment: Thanks for the update Shane.  so you would suggest just placing it in the location / block to simplify?  Isn't it better to split off rewrites into their own block for performance reasons?

Comment: @jimg Since there'd be a regex match needed for the location anyway, the performance impact to evaluating the rewrite for every request is a minimal increase.